# How can I nicely place all the images inside of the container and make it responsive?

Tags: html, css

There are some **images** inside of a blue container. This container lives in a parent container as the one before him. What is the best approach to make it responsive on all devices? What should I change with **media queries**? How to make **different images** inside of a **div container** element not to stack on one another when resizing the **window width**? Thank you.
I have a **figma scratch** that could help you analyze the core of the problem: https://www.figma.com/file/4d3VMi7YiyB62SgmLiOJn9/Sample-Design?node-id=0%3A1&t=dOpflAKWCSL1iCTT-0

[A figma demo example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x9RM.png)

```
<div class="promo-container">
    <div class="promo">
      <div class="promo-info-container">
        <div class="promo-info">
          <h1>Banking Should Be Easy.</h1>
          <p>financial transactions without interet using a mobile device such as a smartphone or tablet with bluetooth. </p>
          <a href="#">Get started</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="promo-images">
        <img class="promo-bottom-left" src="./img/promo/promo-bottom-left.png" alt=""> 
        <img class="promo-top-left" src="./img/promo/promo-top-left.png" alt="">
        <img class="promo-top-right" src="./img/promo/promo-top-right.png" alt="">
        <img class="promo_center" src="./img/promo/promo_center.png" alt="">
        <img class="hard-bottom-right-mask" src="./img/promo/hard-bottom-right-mask.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




 promo-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 75rem;
      padding-left: 8rem;
      padding-right: 8rem;
    }
    
    .promo {
      display: flex;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .promo-info-container {
      width: 50%;
      height: auto;
      background-color: #F3F4FF;
    }
    
    
    .promo-info {
      padding: 19.3rem 9.5rem;
    }
    
    .promo-info h1 {
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 5.5rem;
      line-height: 7rem;
      color: #000;
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
    
    .promo-info p {
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 2rem;
      line-height: 3.4rem;
      letter-spacing: 0.015em;
      color: #363D70;
      margin-bottom: 6.5rem;
    }
    
    .promo-info a {
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: 500;
      line-height: 2rem;
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: #FAFCFF;
      letter-spacing: 0.04em;
      padding: 2.5rem 4.8rem;
      background-color: #3C50E0;
      border-radius: 1.6rem;
    }
    
    
    
    .promo-images {
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
      height: auto;
      background-color: #3C50E0;
    }
    
    .promo-images > * {
      position: absolute;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
    
    .promo-top-left {
      top: 69px;
      left: 86px;
    }
    
    .promo-bottom-left {
      left: 38px;
      bottom: 96px;
    }
    
    .promo-top-right {
      right: 0;
      top: 123px;
    }
    
    .promo_center {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
    
    .hard-bottom-right-mask {
      bottom: 96px;
      right: 67px;
      background-color: #0C1229;
      border-radius: 16px;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code you already have?

Comment: but how you will be able to see the images? they are in the folder

Comment: In your HTML file just provide an absolute or relative path to them, for example `images/file_name.png` for a relative path.

Comment: I've provided the code

Comment: If the right section is just some non-interactive images, then y don't you combine them as a single image and use it in HTML?

Comment: Sadly the sctratch is read only but yeah tha's the first idea I got